# OutOfMemory : Java heap space

Tags: java, websocket, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have a javax based websocket server which acts as communication between two clients running using tomcat9. Application was running fine for 7-8months and as no. of clients start increasing and the websocket calls starts increaing I'm running into `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:335)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInitialHeader(WsFrameBase.java:196)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:171)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:151)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here in the error, it says something with the CharBuffer allocation so I thought it must be related to String and to analyse more about it I took the heap dump of my application and below is the image from JProfiler.

[image]

Here, the char[] is about 6Gb and holds all the usual `onMessage(String message)` calls.

Below is the simplified code from my project

```
public class WsServer {
    
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(WsServer.class);
    static CopyOnWriteArrayList<Session> GlobalSessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Session>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig endpointConfig) {
        GlobalSessions.add(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason reason) {
        
        try {
        
            GlobalSessions.remove(session);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
    }
    
    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable t) {
        
        try {
            session.close(new CloseReason(CloseReason.CloseCodes.VIOLATED_POLICY, t.getMessage()));
            if(t instanceof IOException) {
                logger.error(t.getMessage());
            }else {
                logger.error(t.getMessage(), t);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        
    }

    @OnMessage(maxMessageSize = 5242880)
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        updateLoggerFile(defaultLoggerName);
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(WsServer.class);
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Message messageObj = mapper.readValue(message, Message.class);
            logger.info("message=====>"+messageObj.toString());
            broadcastToUISessions(messageObj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
        
    }
    
    public void broadcastToSessions(Message messageObj) {
        
            GlobalSessions.forEach(eachSession -> {
                try {
    
                    if (eachSession.isOpen()) {
                        synchronized(eachSession) {
                            eachSession.getBasicRemote().sendText(mapper.writeValueAsString(messageObj));
                        }
                    }
    
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
                }
            });
        
    }
    
    

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(PongMessage pongFrame, Session session) throws SchedulerException {
    
        //simple pingpong mechanism to check the client status

    }
    
    static void updateLoggerFile(String filename) {
        System.setProperty("abcFileName", ""+filename+".log");
    }
}
```

From the code you can see that I'm not storing the message String in any global variable, each time a new message comes, the previous message gets deferrenced and should be garbage collected.
But these messages are still retained in the GC as soft reference.

Am I missing something here?
Shouldn't the String value get cleared from the heap periodically every time GC runs?
Should I manually call the `System.GC()` manually every hour (or after particular intervals)?
Should I set some JAVA_OPTS for GC?

One temprory solution I found was to reduce the maxMessageSize from 5Mb to 1Mb for `onMessage()`  and reduce the memory occupancy to 1/5th.

I have set JVM max heap size as `-Xmx8192m`

Comment: Is that a whole stacktrace of java heap space? If not could you drop as a code to your post whole instead of screenshot? How long does your application work before OutOfMemory happens?

Comment: Manually calling `System.GC()` is not a good idea. You can use the following flag `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to get a heap dump before OOO. You can then analyse the heap. I suggest using [Eclipse Memory Analizer](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) as it helps you discovering where all the objects are being held instead of being garbage collected. If the error has started happening just because an increase of users, then you just may simply need more heap (as you have stated with `-Xmx8192m`). But you should check if there is a memory leak.

Comment: @RafałSokalski Updated the stacktrace as code instead of screenshot and yes, that is the whole stacktrace. Application works fine for few days until the memory reaches max assigned and thus ends up with OutOfMemory

Comment: could you also share code for sendText method?

Comment: @usuario Checked with Eclipse Memory Analizer, it shows that the 80% of memory is utilized by a GlobalSessions object which holds the list of open sessions.

Comment: @RafałSokalski that code is present in ```broadcastToSessions()```

Comment: `eachSession.getBasicRemote().sendText(mapper.writeValueAsString(messageObj));` That sendText method is not present in your post.

Comment: @RafałSokalski that is an in-built java library method associated with Session object to send the message to that particular session

Comment: @rahul, so the problem lies in that GlobalSessions object. You have a couple of options. **A)** Maybe there is a bug/issue and sessions are not cleared/removed after being closed. Check if number or active sessions relates the number of sessions stored in the object. I am not familiar with websockets, what type of class is GlobalSessions? maybe you are not removing them when onError **B)** Or maybe as you now have a higher number of users, you just need more heap to allocate all of them.

Comment: @usuario from the top command I can see that if number of clients decrese, memory utilization gets reduced. From this I came to conclusion that my server needs more heap allocation i.e., accepting your **B** case. But my question was, why am I still able to see the oldest of socket messages in my heap dump? Will those messages be there until the session gets deleted?

Comment: @rahul after a full gc, all not reachable objects are cleaned from the heap. So if you see an object in the heap after a full gc, that object is somehow still referenced in your code. If that is not the desired behaviour, there is something wrong in code implementation. Heap objects are not GC cleaned based on age, but on reachability. Using Eclipse Memory Analizer you can track objects to its roots, so as to see who is holding references to that object.

Comment: @usuario I figured out that as long as I keep hold of session objects, the messages sent to those sessions are still stored in the heap. These messages are still holding the reference of messages sent to those sessions and that's why the heap has this data store still. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you must be saving them in your `Session` object.

Answer (score 0):

> static CopyOnWriteArrayList GlobalSessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();

This is a code smell to me. Statically initialized instance most of the time creates a memory leak. Check best practices to avoid memory leak.